# Why does Takeshi Yamamoto have a interesting naming sense?

Tags: japanese-language, reborn

In Katekyo Hitman Reborn, Haru mentions that Takeshi has a interesting sense of naming.

Now I were wondering, is this only because he added the 'Ko' character to the name? Or is there a deeper, under-laying joke/reference made there?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jirou is an [Akita Inu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akita_(dog)), while Kojirou is a [swallow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swallow). They are named similarly because they are two halves of Yamamoto's Vongola Box.

Kojirou is named after the swordsman [Sasaki Kojirou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sasaki_Kojir%C5%8D), known as the rival of Miyamoto Musashi and for his "Tsubame Gaeshi" (Turning Swallow Cut) technique that is said to mimic the motion of a swallow's tail.

Jirou is probably named after [one of](http://www.tofugu.com/2012/08/02/notable-japanese-dogs/) the two [Sakhalin Husky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sakhalin_Husky) sled dogs that survived [an ill-fated Japanese Polar expedition](http://www.digitaljournal.com/article/337391). While the breed is currently extinct, they are said to be one of the [precursors](http://www.japanesedog.org/karafuto-ken-sakhalin-husky/) to the modern Akita Inu.

These two animal were not only named after figures of historical origin, but also share similarities to one another as they are both two parts of a whole. The "ko" in Kojirou means "small/little."